# remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-admin'); function not removing dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a new role in WordPress for WooCommerce. The only thing I require this role to see is:

- WooCommerce --> Orders Only
- Users - All Submenus
- WP All Import - All Submenus except for Settings
- WP All Export - All Submenus except for Settings

I successfully dwindled down to the list but am having issues isolating the WooCommerce Dashboard sub-menu.

I used this code to get a full list:

```
    if (!function_exists('debug_admin_menus')):
function debug_admin_menus() {
if ( !is_admin())
        return;
    global $submenu, $menu, $pagenow;
    if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) { // ONLY DO THIS FOR ADMIN
        if( $pagenow == 'index.php' ) {  // PRINTS ON DASHBOARD
            echo '<pre>'; print_r( $menu ); echo '</pre>'; // TOP LEVEL MENUS
            echo '<pre>'; print_r( $submenu ); echo '</pre>'; // SUBMENUS
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'debug_admin_menus' );
endif;
```

I found that component being: wc-admin where I added:

```
remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-admin');
```

BUT it isn't removing it. Does anyone know why? I've also tried:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_pages', 999);
function remove_menu_pages() {
  global $current_user;

  $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
  $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
  if($user_role == "custom_shop_admin") {
    $remove_submenu = remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-admin');
  }
}
```

Everywhere I've looked up has ('woocommerce', 'wc-admin') as the dashboard. Not sure if I can't remove it, to redirect it to the orders page perhaps for that role only. I know there has been a recent WooCommerce Update so not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Thank you!

Comment: Check `$remove_submenu` value, documentation on [remove_submenu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/) says it's false, if submenu isn't found and thus not deleted

Comment: Thanks Alex, I actually did do that via the code above, I tried the alternate method in one of the suggestions, but it's only bringing in blank entries in the error log file. The first way I have it display via the Dashboard

Comment: `[woocommerce] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Dashboard
                    [1] => view_woocommerce_reports
                    [2] => wc-admin
                    [3] => Dashboard`

Comment: Also tried: admin.php?page=wc-admin

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: I could not. I did a work around keeping the Dashboard, but removing the items within the dashboard with CSS for that specific role. Keeping this thread alive to see if anyone can figure it out. It would be good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a long time no talk here. I had the same problem. I have figured it out and it may help people out in the future to solve the problem really quick. Here is the solution.

```
function remove_menus_custom(){
global $current_user;
if(is_admin(){
remove_submenu_page('woocommerce','wc-admin'); 
}
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus_custom', 999 );
```